# loop jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simply try to assign a background color to each div.
it looks simple but it doesn't work.

```
var divElements = $("div");
var colorArray =["444", "344", "345", "472", "837", "043", "345", "472", "837", "043"];

for (var i=0; i< divElements.length; i++){
divElements[i].css("background","#"+colorArray[i])
}
```

I also tried to use jQuery's each

```
$("div").each(function(i) {
  divElements[i].css("background","#"+colorArray[i])
})
```

How do code this in javaScript generic "for loop" and jQuerys .each()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("div").each(function(i, val) {
  $(this).css("background", "#" + colorArray[i]);
});
```

You have to watch out for exceeding the bounds of colorArray though (ie if you get too many divs). Possibilities include stopping when you hit the max:

```
$("div").each(function(i, val) {
  if (i > colorArray.length) {
    return false; // breaks $.each() loop
  }
  $(this).css("background", "#" + colorArray[i]);
});
```

or cycle through them:

```
$("div").each(function(i, val) {
  $(this).css("background", "#" + colorArray[i & colorArray.length]);
});
```

Not sure why you'd want to do it as Javascript but:

```
var divElements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var colorArray =["444", "344", "345", "472", "837", "043", "345", "472", "837", "043"];
for (var i=0; i< divElements.length; i++){
  divElements[i].style.backgroundColor = '#' + colorArray[i];
}
```

Comment: Great, how do i write this in generic js!

Comment: for a project that will sadly not use jQuery

Comment: Um, if it doesn't use jQuery, how are you getting $("div")?

Comment: it was just for my question purpose.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

**Here's what you do:**

```
var colors = ["#444", "#344", etc.];

$("div").each(function (i)
{
    $(this).css("background-color", colors[i]);
});
```

You might get a small speed-gain if you skip converting "this" into a jQuery object and just use the JavaScript native API, like so:

```
this.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
```

Also, you might want to assign a default color, if you've got more DIV-elements than entries in your array:

```
this.style.backgroundColor = colors[i] || "#fff";
```

**The native approach:**

```
var colors = ["#444", "#344", etc.],
    divElements = document.getElementsByTagName("div"),
    i = divElements.length;

while (i)
{
    // This is a reverse while-loop and runs a lot faster than other methods.
    // This means that the first div element will get assigned the value of the
    // last entry in the "colors"-array. If this breaks your brain, use the
    // Array.reverse() function on the "colors"-array declaration :)

    i--;

    divElements[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i] || "#fff";
}
```

Comment: This answers the non-jQuery question well.

Comment: +1 for nice code even if it´s not answering the original question.

Answer (score 0):

try `background-color` instead of `background`, which is the shorthand for multiple other CSS rules.

```
divElements[h].css("background-color","#"+colorArray[h])
```